# Excel vba: constant expression required in for cycle

Tags: vba, excel

I have a function that returns a `Dictionary` with pairs key-value. Then I proceed to use on such pair to create an array: I get a value for key "DATA_ITEMS_NUMBER" to determine arrays' max length. However it results in an error...

```
   Function getGlobalVariables()
          Dim resultDict As Object
          Set resultDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

          resultDict.Add "DATA_ITEMS_NUMBER", _
                    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("setup").Cells(25, 5).value

          Set getGlobalVariables = resultDict
    End Function

    Function getBudgetItemInfos(infoType As String, year As Integer)
          Dim globals As Object
          Set globals = getGlobalVariables()

          Dim DATA_ITEMS_NUMBER As Integer
          DATA_ITEMS_NUMBER = globals("DATA_ITEMS_NUMBER")



          Dim resultArray(1 To DATA_ITEMS_NUMBER) As String

    ...
    End Function
```

Comment: I think you need to dim the array first: `Dim resultArray()` and then resize it after you get `DATA_ITEMS_NUMBER` : `Redim resultArray(1 To DATA_ITEMS_NUMBER)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Dim` statement isn't executable; you can't put a breakpoint on a `Dim` statement, it "runs" as soon as the local scope is entered, in "static context", i.e. it doesn't (and can't) know about anything that lives in "execution context", like other local variables' values.

Hence, `Dim foo(1 To SomeVariable)` is illegal, because `SomeVariable` is not a *constant expression* that's known at compile-time: without the *execution context*, `SomeVariable` has no value and the array can't be statically sized.

If you want a dynamically-sized array, you need to *declare* a dynamic array - the `ReDim` statement is executable:

```
ReDim resultArray(1 To DATA_ITEMS_NUMBER) As String
```

Note that a `Dim resultArray()` statement isn't necessary, since `ReDim` is going to perform the allocation anyway: you won't get a "variable not declared" compile-time error with a `ReDim foo(...)` without a preceding `Dim foo` and `Option Explicit` specified.

For good form your `Function` procedures should have an explicit return type though:

```
'returns a Scripting.Dictionary instance
Function getGlobalVariables() As Object
```

And

```
'returns a Variant array
Function getBudgetItemInfos(infoType As String, year As Integer) As Variant
```

Otherwise (especially for the `Object`-returning function), you're wrapping your functions' return values in a `Variant`, and VBA needs to work harder than it should, at the call sites.